# Entire functions satisfying a given condition

Tags: complex-analysis

"n" is a given positive integer. Find all entire functions satisfying $f^n(z)=z$ for every z in $\mathbb C$

Not getting any ideas. Can someone help please?

Comment: is the $n$ indicating the derivative or a power?  If the latter, and if $n > 1$ there are no such entire functions.  $f(z) = z^{1/n} $ for $n > 1$ always has a branch point at $z=0$.

Comment: If $f^n$ denotes the $n$-fold composition $f\circ f \circ \ldots \circ f$, there are solutions.

Comment: n denotes composition of f with itself n times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is one-to-one, so by Picard's "great" theorem it can't have an essential singularity at $\infty$.  We conclude that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $1$, and then it's easy to show $f(z) = c z + d$ where $c$ is an $n$'th root of unity (with $d=0$ in the case $c = 1$).

Comment: Thank you very much for the crisp answer.